# Convert a HashMap<Integer, Long> ito HashMap<Integer, Integer>

Tags: java, casting, integer, long-integer, collectors

`Collectors.counting()` returns `long` values for each key in this method:

```
private static Map<Integer, Long> countDuplicates(HashSet<Card> cards) {
    return cards.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Card::getRankNumber, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Is there a way to cast or convert the resulting `Map` from `Map<Integer, Long>` to `Map<Integer, Integer>`?

Direct casting gives this exception:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Integer,Integer> to Map<Integer,Long>
```

**Note:** The implementation of my class guarantees that `cards` has five objects in it, so **there is no chance of overflow.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> countDuplicates(HashSet<Card> cards) {
    return cards.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Card::getRankNumber, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));
}
```

Instead of `Collectors.counting()` use `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)` so that you get immediately the value as an Integer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get `Map<Integer, Integer>` is to use `toMap` collector along with `Integer::sum` [method reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Method_references) as a merge function:

```java
private static Map<Integer, Integer> countDuplicates(HashSet<Card> cards) {
    return cards.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Card::getRankNumber, x -> 1, Integer::sum));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the [Answer by dreamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65910215/642706) and the [Answer by Alex Rudenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65910400/642706) seem correct. Here is example code I wrote to try both approaches.

The `Card` class.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Card
{
    public enum Suit
    {
        CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE
    }

    // -------------|  Member fields  |-----------------------
    private Suit suit;
    private String name;
    private Integer rankNumber;

    // -------------|  Constructors  |-----------------------
    public Card ( Suit suit , String name , Integer rankNumber )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( suit );
        Objects.requireNonNull( name );
        Objects.requireNonNull( rankNumber );
        this.suit = suit;
        this.name = name;
        this.rankNumber = rankNumber;
    }

    // -------------|  Getters  |-----------------------
    public String getName ( ) { return this.name; }

    public Integer getRankNumber ( ) { return this.rankNumber; }


    // -------------|  Object methods  |-----------------------

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Card{ " +
                "suit=" + suit +
                " | name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | rankNumber=" + rankNumber +
                " }";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Card card = ( Card ) o;
        return suit == card.suit && getName().equals( card.getName() ) && getRankNumber().equals( card.getRankNumber() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( suit , getName() , getRankNumber() );
    }
}
```

In Java 16 and later, we could reduce that `Card` class to a brief [`record`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). And in the code further down we would change `getRankNumber` to the implicit getter method `rankNumber`. The `Suit` enum would move to its own .java file.

```java
package work.basil.example.cardgame;

public record Card( Suit suit , String name , Integer rankNumber )
{
}
```

The `CastingStream` class to collect those cards.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CastingStream
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        CastingStream app = new CastingStream();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Set < Card > cards = Set.of(
                new Card( Card.Suit.HEART , "Ten" , 10 ) ,
                new Card( Card.Suit.SPADE , "Ten" , 10 ) ,
                new Card( Card.Suit.HEART , "Queen" , 12 )
        );

        // Code taken from Question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65910153/642706
        Map < Integer, Long > countDuplicatesLong =
                cards
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        Card :: getRankNumber ,
                                        Collectors.counting()
                                )
                        );

        // Code taken from Answer by dreamcrash. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65910215/642706
        Map < Integer, Integer > countDuplicatesIntegerBySummingInt =
                cards
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        Card :: getRankNumber ,
                                        Collectors.summingInt( x -> 1 )
                                )
                        );

        // Code taken from Answer by Alex Rudenko. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65910400/642706
        Map < Integer, Integer > countDuplicatesIntegerBySumMethodReference =
                cards
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.toMap( Card :: getRankNumber ,
                                        x -> 1 ,
                                        Integer :: sum
                                )
                        );


        System.out.println( "cards = " + cards );
        System.out.println( "countDuplicatesLong = " + countDuplicatesLong );
        System.out.println( "countDuplicatesIntegerBySummingInt = " + countDuplicatesIntegerBySummingInt );
        System.out.println( "countDuplicatesIntegerBySumMethodReference = " + countDuplicatesIntegerBySumMethodReference );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
cards = [Card{ suit=HEART | name='Queen' | rankNumber=12 }, Card{ suit=HEART | name='Ten' | rankNumber=10 }, Card{ suit=SPADE | name='Ten' | rankNumber=10 }]
countDuplicatesLong = {10=2, 12=1}
countDuplicatesIntegerBySummingInt = {10=2, 12=1}
countDuplicatesIntegerBySumMethodReference = {10=2, 12=1}
```

Comment: LOL it would be awkward if the results were different in the end xD